# Why isn't my text changing to the color code I put in? (It stays blue)

Tags: html, css, colors

This is the code, as you can see I'm trying to change the color to a grey, but every time I preview the changes and/or save it stays blue.

```
#title {
position:fixed;
font-size:40px;
font-family: 'Jim Nightshade', cursive;
text-align:center;
padding-bottom:1px;
bottom:90px;
margin-left:0px;
width:500px;
height:-10px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
color:#a4a4a4;
line-height:100%;;
z-index:999999999;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
```

Comment: I am sure you are targeting nested `a` element, right?

Comment: can you provide your HTML code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the wrapper to `#title a {}`, since I'm assuming you're talking about hyperlinks.

Comment: oh no. now when i hover over it will not change color.

Comment: sorry, haven't checked my notifs in a while. `#title a, #title a:hover {}` should take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of specificity, try adding !important to your color property.

```
#title {
position:fixed;
font-size:40px;
font-family: 'Jim Nightshade', cursive;
text-align:center;
padding-bottom:1px;
bottom:90px;
margin-left:0px;
width:500px;
height:-10px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
color:#a4a4a4 !important;
line-height:100%;;
z-index:999999999;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using anchor within "title" element, that's why your browser is rendering default anchor color i.e blue.

Suppose you are having an html like

```
<div id="title">
 <a href="#">Test Color</a>
</div>
```

If you apply CSS to "title" div as

```
#title {
position:fixed;
font-size:40px;
font-family: 'Jim Nightshade', cursive;
text-align:center;
padding-bottom:1px;
bottom:90px;
margin-left:0px;
width:500px;
height:-10px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
color:#a4a4a4;
line-height:100%;;
z-index:999999999;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

It will give blue color for text "Test Color"

Refer to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/E4K6B/1/) for such effect

But if you apply CSS to "a" within "title" as

```
#title a{
text-decoration:none;
position:fixed;
font-size:40px;
font-family: 'Jim Nightshade', cursive;
text-align:center;
padding-bottom:1px;
bottom:90px;
margin-left:0px;
width:500px;
height:-10px;
padding:5px;
overflow:hidden;
color:#a4a4a4;
line-height:100%;;
z-index:999999999;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;  
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

It will show grey color for anchor too.

**The updated code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/E4K6B/2/)**